# R Frequency table of multiple columns, grouped by third variable

Tags: r

I have a data table that looks like this with "groups" of columns that belong together:

- Group 1: Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3
- Group 2: Q2_1, Q2_2

```
 ID Sex  Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q2_1 Q2_2 
 1   m    2     5    2    4    4
 2   f    4     5    1    3    1
 3   m    5     4    4    5    5
 4   f    2     4    3    5    4
```

First, I would like to count all values that appear across all rows in that group of columns and create a new data table out of it that should look like this:

```
 answer  freq_Q1_all  freq_Q2_all 
    1         1            1
    2         3            0
    3         1            1
    4         4            3
    5         3            3
```

And last, I would like to create a similar data table but separated by variables of column *Sex*.

```
 answer  freq_Q1_all_f  freq_Q1_all_m  freq_Q2_all_f  freq_Q2_all_m
    1         1              0               1               0
    2         1              2               0               0
    3         1              0               1               0
    4         2              2               1               2
    5         2              1               1               2
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/):

First question:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Q"), values_to = "answer") %>%
    separate(name, into = c("question", "question2")) %>%
    count(question, answer) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = n) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)

  answer    Q1    Q2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     1     1
2      2     3     0
3      3     1     1
4      4     4     3
5      5     3     3
```

Second question:

```
dat %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Q"), values_to = 'answer') %>%
    separate(name, into = c("question", "question2")) %>%
    count(Sex, question, answer)  %>%
    unite(question, question, Sex, sep = "_") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = n) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)

  answer  Q1_f  Q2_f  Q1_m  Q2_m
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     1     1     0     0
2      2     1     0     2     0
3      3     1     1     0     0
4      4     2     1     2     2
5      5     1     1     2     2
```

The major work you need to do for this is just reshaping the data, which is where we use [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) (could also use gather) and [`pivot_wider`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) (could also use spread). [`separate`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) and [`unite`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html) help us to clean up columns that need to be separated (`Q1_1` -> `Q1`, `1`) and united (`Q1`, `f` -> `Q1_f`). From there it is just a little data cleanup.

If you are unfamiliar with these functions, it might be helpful to step through the operations, executing the code line-by-line.

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, 
                      Sex = c("m", "f", "m", "f"), 
                      Q1_1 = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 2L), 
                      Q1_2 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), 
                      Q1_3 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), 
                      Q2_1 = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 5L), 
                      Q2_2 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 4L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works.
Just for my understanding: How exactly does `separate` work? Where do you define the object `name` and where do the names "question" and "question2" appear?

Comment: `name` comes from the result of  `pivot_longer`. `question` and `question2` will be in the data.frame after executing `separate`. you might want to look at executing the statements one-by-one to see the "internal" operations